# Undisable paste on the California DMV website

Tags: javascript

The CA DMV has a [website](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/FIM/sps/uscfed/usc/self/account/create) that disables pasting in some non-standard way, as none of the standard techniques (setting the correct option in about:config for Firefox, extensions for Firefox or Chrome) for correcting this behavior works.  When you try to paste into one of the disallowed fields, it pops up a dialog that says, "Sorry, this functionality is disabled."

1. How is this done?
2. How do I correct it?

Comment: My question is, WHY do they do this? What makes them think disabling paste is somehow more secure? (They also disable paste on other password-masked fields, like where you enter your bank account and routing number for paying registration fees - you have to type these long, seldom-used numbers manually twice each)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see how it's done in the source HTML - they have an inline `keydown` attribute:

```
<input class="entry-field" name="usc.form.password.new.confirm" id="password_new_confirm" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="3" onmousedown="whichButton(event, 'Sorry, this functionality is disabled.')" onkeydown="return noCTRL(event, 'Sorry, this functionality is disabled.')" type="password" />
```

One option would be to write a userscript that intercepts `keydown` events in the *capturing* phase, and calls `stopPropagation()` so that the event doesn't capture down to the listener on the restricted fields (like the "Verify Password" and "Email Address" fields):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Reenable Paste
// @namespace    CertainPerformance
// @version      1
// @match        https://www.dmv.ca.gov/FIM/sps/uscfed/usc/self/account/create
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

It has already been mentioned why this happens: essentially, there are event listeners on the `input` elements that detect and block right-click and <kbd>control</kbd> key events. (Expand the snippet below to see the functions that do this.)

```js
function whichButton(event, msg) {
  if (event.button == 2)//RIGHT CLICK
  {
    alert(msg);
  }
}

function noCTRL(e, msg) {
  var code = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
  if (parseInt(code) == 17) //CTRL
  {
    alert(msg);
    window.event.returnValue = false;
  }
}
```

While the answer already mentioned (preventing `keydown` propagation) addresses the <kbd>control</kbd> key issue, it does not re-enable right-click. I would assert that the simplest solution to this issue is simply to redefine the `whichButton` and `noCTRL` functions called by the event listeners to be blank. To do this is trivial:

```
whichButton = noCTRL = () => {}
```

You could wrap this in a userscript like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Reenable Paste on CA DMV
// @match        https://www.dmv.ca.gov/FIM/sps/uscfed/usc/self/account/create
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

whichButton = noCTRL = () => {}
```

To use the userscript, you'll need to install [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).